# Add certain end to all the internal links on the page

Tags: javascript

I need some simple code on pure JavaScript (NOT jQuery!) that will add certain end to all the internal links on a page (i.e. to all the links that contain website domain in its href attribute), something like:

```
var pagelinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i in pagelinks) {
  if(pagelinks.getAttribute('href').indexOf(document.domain) != -1) {
    pagelinks[i].setAttribute('href',currenthref+'my_end');
  }
}
```

**!!! NOTE:** it's not working script — it's only "something like" what I need

For example the internal links on a page are:

```
<a href="http//mysite.com/showcase">Showcase</a>
<a href="http//mysite.com/contacts">Contacts</a>
...
```

I need

```
<a href="http//mysite.com/showcase?my_end">Showcase</a>
<a href="http//mysite.com/contacts?my_end">Contacts</a>
...
```

Comment: What is the problem with the above then?

Comment: Does it work? It's only the "something like". I don't know how to get the variable currenthref and how to specify condition "if link contains domain"

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: i don't think your internal links contain an absolute URL, most probably they are all relative, so you should reflect that in your script. Also the script is not functional, e.g. `var i in pagelinks` is like confusing numerical with member iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct this is what you want:

```
var domain = 'www.youtube.com';

var pagelinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < pagelinks.length; i++) {

  var current = pagelinks[i].getAttribute('href');

  if (current.indexOf(domain) !== -1) {
    pagelinks[i].setAttribute('href', current + '?my_end');
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cm69qmnL/6/

You have to specify the domain you want to check the `href` attributes against and then run a loop which checks each anchor's `href` attribute, checks it against the specified domain and updated the `href` if the domain exists in `current`.

Comment: @stckvrw Could you update your question and explain exactly what you want?

Comment: i have updated his fiddle. it was just missing to prepend the original url https://jsfiddle.net/cm69qmnL/3/

Comment: but, without jQuery and its `document.ready`, don't forget to place that script before `</body>`, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @stckvrw Updated my answer, can you check now?

Comment: Yes, it works. But @wiesion was right: if I move the cursor over the internal link on the browser I see its full URL but actually in html it has _relative_ URL. So can you replace the condition in your code with condition "if current doesn't contain any domain" i.e. for all the links without domain in html ?

Comment: @stckvrw I'm not sure what you mean, the HTML is updated with this code. So whatever you see when you hover is actually there in the HTML href attribute.

Comment: @stckvrw Is that really a problem though? Because it will still execute as long as you specify the domain name, irrelevant of the path to the domain. The domain name, www.youtube.com as in the example, can have either stuff in front of it or after it and the if statement will still execute. I can't seem to understand why this is an issue or how to fix it since I can't actually see what the problem is.

Comment: The point is the script doesn't work if I specify your if statement (for as I mentioned the internal URLs are relative so the statement doesn't work). If I remove the if statement it works but for all the links on the page, including the links to some external websites like social networks and so on. But the script should add the end ONLY to the internal links. I try `if(current.indexOf('http://') === 0) {` but it doesn't work too